# "Attach" comments or discussions to files

Tags: dropbox

I am looking for a way to record discussion about documents within a shared Dropbox folder. I'm hoping to have such comments "attach" to the document rather than having to achieve it within another document, inline, or via comments.

Comment: that's actually something we're looking to perhaps add to our product http://orangedox.com/dropbox .. what's the use case?

Answer (score 1):

[Announced April 28, 2015: Feedback made easy: Add comments on Dropbox files](https://blog.dropbox.com/topics/product/commenting-now-available)

> Today we’re simplifying that process. With comments, you can now have conversations around Dropbox files, both on the files you own and the files people share with you. This keeps your conversations organized in one place, and provides a way to gather feedback in just one step. Here are a few ways you can use commenting to make life easier:
>
> - **Bring anyone into the conversation with mentions.** When you type @, followed by someone’s name or email address, they’ll get an email notification — even if they don’t use Dropbox — with a link to go right to the file. It’s a one-step process to both share a file and gather input about it.
> - **Instantly stay up to date (if you choose).** When anyone comments on a file you’ve shared, you’ll receive an email notification. Or if you don’t need play-by-play updates on a certain file, just click ‘Unsubscribe from notifications.’
> - **Manage the conversation.** Everyone with access to a shared link can make comments. But what if you don’t want others to be able to weigh in? If it’s a file you shared, just click ‘Turn off comments’ in the Options menu.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://dropboxmainblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/animate.gif?w=650&h=401))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

We believe it is possible to share and collaborate the folders with the message for the user about the document but having comment discussion about shared documents is not possible.

As a work around you can create separate txt file with in the folder only for the users discussion with the name (Discussion.txt) and with the help of "view and sync" permission users can able to add the comment which would get reflect for all user when accessing the txt file.

Hope this helps!